# ファイル変換のRubyスクリプトに「'getbit':undefined method '」というエラーが出ます

Tags: ruby

プログラミング素人で、質問のRubyスクリプトの開発者でもありません。

ファイル形式変換のRubyスクリプトを使おうとしたら、エラーが出て途中で止まってしまいます。

手持ちの辞書ソフトをスマホ・タブレットで使えるように、辞書データをEPWINGに変換しようとしていますが、[こちらの](http://hp.vector.co.jp/authors/VA005784/btonic/btonic2xml.html)Rubyスクリプトでテキストに変換しようとしたら下記のエラーが出ます。

> C:/work/BTONIX2xml.rb:57in 'getbit':undefined method '>>' for "\xF0":String (NoMethodError)

スクリプトが10年前のもののようで互換性の問題でしょうと思い、様々バージョン・環境で試しましたが自力で解決できませんでした。試した環境はWindows 7 32bitと64bit、RubyInstallerでインストールしたRuby 1.8x、1.9x、2.0x、2.2xです。

ちなみに使ったコマンドはこちらです：

> ruby -Ks C:\work\BTONIC2xml.rb "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\（辞書ソフトのフォルダー）\（辞書名）\（辞書名）.exi" C:\btonic

スクリプトのコードのどこかを修正できれば行けるかもしれないと思い、こちらに来ました。

どなたか何か教えていただけると非常にありがたいです。 m(__)m

Comment: 複数のバージョンの ruby が入っていて、意図しないバージョンの ruby が使われていた、ということはありませんか?

Comment: お返事ありがとうございました。何回もいろんなことをやっていたつもりなのに、恥ずかしいことにおっしゃるとおり、Rubyをすべてアンインストールし、1.8xのみ再インストールしたらようやく出来ました。ありがとうございました！

Answer (score 0):

（コメント欄より)

複数バージョンの ruby がインストールされていて、意図しないバージョンが利用されていたことが原因の様子です。

Rubyをすべてアンインストールし、1.8xのみ再インストールしたところ問題は解決しました。。